# What concurrent collection do I use here?

Tags: c#, collections, .net-4.5

I need to be able to enumerate the collection in any order (foreach) and Add/Remove an item from any thread.

Direct access by index is not needed.

What collection do I use? Simply a List? If so, do I only have to lock on add/remove or do I have to lock on foreach also?

I want the following operations to be available on any thread.

```
foreach (var item in myCollection)
{
    // myCollection can be returned in any order.
}

myCollection.Add(item)

var success = myCollection.Remove(item) // returns false if the item does not exist in myCollection
```

Comment: He means it doesn't matter in which order the elements are returned.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You sould use [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) for thread-safe collections, which `Represents a thread-safe, unordered collection of objects`, which is avaliable since `.NET 4.0`

note: I can't give more information because I'm not aware of the context, in which you are going to use it. Provide more information for a deeper answer.

Comment: I can't remove a specific object though?

Comment: use `TryTake` - `Attempts to remove and return an object from the ConcurrentBag<T>.`

Comment: But it may not be the object I want to remove! Sorry I didn't make it clear. See my edits to the OP. I want to be able to specify the object that I want to remove.

Comment: `Remove from any thread` is quite a tricky requirement. You can see no collection from `System.Collections.Concurrent` implements removal by instance, only `Take` and `TryTake` are implemented. I don't know your scenario, but why don't you try to stick with this model? You can see more details on why no removal by instance here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695627/concurrent-collection-supporting-removal-of-a-specified-item