# Is there anything like a ConcurrentSet in .Net?

Tags: .net, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrentdictionary

I've used the `ConcurrentDictionary` in .Net and fell in love with how easy it is to write concurrent classes using it.

Now, I have a different scenario though. I basically need to keep track of a single object type in an non-duplicated unordered list, so basically a `Set<T>` type thing, except for it needs all of the thread-safety I've come to expect from `ConcurrentDictionary`, so having things like `GetOrAdd`.

Is there anything like this built into .Net?

I've considered just using ConcurrentDictionary and only worrying about the key, and never using the value, but this seems very sub-optimal

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306936/how-to-implement-concurrenthashset-in-net

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create a thread-safe set by referencing FSharp.Core.dll and using Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.

Just wrap adds and removes with an interlocked.CompareExhchange.

Performance varies with set size. But you should able to handle several hundred thousand set items.

This handles lots of threads reading and writing to the set.

Also the "Lock" (not really a lock, just the area of atomic actions) is around everything between the lines:

initialSet = sharedSet;

and

done = (initialSet == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sharedSet, newSet, initialSet));

```
 FSharpSet<MyClass> _myItems;

 InterLockedSetAdd(ref _myItems, Item);

    public static void InterLockedSetAdd<T>(ref FSharpSet<T> sharedSet, T item)
    {

        FSharpSet<T> initialSet;
        FSharpSet<T> newSet;
        var spin = new SpinWait();
        bool done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            initialSet = sharedSet;
            newSet = sharedSet.Add(item);
            done = (initialSet == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sharedSet, newSet, initialSet));
            if (!done) spin.SpinOnce();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why use FSharpSet? Why not use HashSet from System.Collections.Generic?

Comment: Because `FSharpSet` is immutable. If you used a `HashSet` then the solution wouldn't be thread safe. Nowadays, you could use something like `ImmutableHashSet`.