# How to iterate over users in asp.net core SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, claims

In a SignalR application on .net core, I have a working piece of code similar to the following:

```
public Task SendPrivateMessage(string user, string message)
{
    var sender = Context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.Type == "username")?.Value;
    return Clients.User(user)
                  .SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"Message from {sender}: {message}");
}
```

This sends a message from the currently connected user, to the specified user.

Now I'd like to send an individual message to *every* user connected; something like the following concept:

```
public Task UpdateMessageStatus()
{
    foreach(client in Clients.Users)
    {
         var nrOfMessages = GetMessageCount();
         client.SendAsync($"You have {nrOfMessages} messages.");
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this; i.e. how can I iterate over connected users, and send individual messages to each of them?

**Edit / clarification**

As mentioned, I needed to send *individual* (i.e. specialized) messages to each connected user, so using `Clients.All` was not an option, as that can only be used to send the same message to all connected users.

I ended up doing something similar to what Mark C. posted in the accepted answer.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is with the current version of `UpdateMessageStatus` please ?

Comment: Currently there are no properties exposed to get the connected users or connection ids, but you can keep a list of users currently connected to the Hub with OnConnected and OnDisconnected events. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#in-memory-storage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're deadset on not using the `Clients.All` API that is given to you, you can keep a local cache of the connected users and use that as your list of connected users.

Something like this :

```
static HashSet<string> CurrentConnections = new HashSet<string>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;
        CurrentConnections.Add(id);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public Task SendAllClientsMessage()
    {
        foreach (var activeConnection in GetAllActiveConnections())
        {
            Clients.Client(activeConnection).SendMessageAsync("Hi");
        }
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var connection = CurrentConnections.FirstOrDefault(x => x == Context.ConnectionId);

        if (connection != null)
        {
            CurrentConnections.Remove(connection);
        }

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }


    //return list of all active connections
    public List<string> GetAllActiveConnections()
    {
        return CurrentConnections.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Just for clarification, because @Mark C. did not say it explicitely: ASP.NET (neither core nor pure) store a collection containing users for you. You have to maintain that on your own.(like shown above)

Comment: Any idea how to apply the above approach, but with injected hubcontext?

Comment: @Yahia You still need to store the connections in some form, and use that storage to pull the clients that you want to broadcast to. I dont think much changes here

Comment: You are right. I ended up defining `SendAllClientsMessage as static in the hub, and using it from the hubcontext

Comment: You should be using a thread safe collection - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18923091/16940 - The regular HashSet WILL come and bite you someday!

Comment: I agree, use a `ConcurrentBag` or whatever collection type that fits the requirements.

Comment: Or locking. This example is going to get someone in trouble - which is ultimately the fault of the person copying code, but others will pay the price.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Clients.All to send message to your all clients.

> return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"Message from
>   {sender}: {message}");

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an managing my own list of connected users, similar to the [answer provided by Mark C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51382662/336648).

Just to expand on it slightly, this will allow me to do something like the following concept:

```
public async Task CheckAllMessages()
{
    foreach (var user in ConnectedUsers)
    {
       var nr = GetNrOfMessagesForUser(user);
       if(nr > 0)
       {
           await Clients.User(user)
                        .SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", 
                                   $"User ({user}) has {nr} new messages waiting.");
       }
    }
}
```