# trying to replace a lock() with a SpinWait.SpinUntil() but it doesnt work

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, spinwait

let start with the code;

`checkedUnlock` is an `HashSet<ulong>`

`_hashsetLock` is an object

```
lock (_hashsetLock)
    newMap = checkedUnlock.Add(uniqueId);
```

vs

`fun` in an int

```
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref fun, 1, 0) == 1);
newMap = checkedUnlock.Add(uniqueId);
fun = 0;
```

my understanding is the `SpinWait` in this scenario should work like the `lock()` but there is more items added in the `HashSet`, sometime it match lock, sometime there is 1 to 5 more items in it, which make it obvious that it doesnt work

is my understanding flawed?

**edit**

I tried this and it seem to work, my test show the same number as `lock()` so far

```
SpinWait spin = new SpinWait();
while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref fun, 1, 0) == 1)
   spin.SpinOnce();
```

so why would it work with this but not  `SpinWait.SpinUntil()` ?

**edit #2**

small full application to see

in this code, the `SpinWait.SpinUntil` will sometime blow up (the add will throw an exception) but when it work, the count will be different so my expected behavior for this one is wrong

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<int>();
            var rnd = new Random(42);
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
                list.Add(rnd.Next(500000));



            object _lock1 = new object();
            var hashset1 = new HashSet<int>();

            int _lock2 = 0;
            var hashset2 = new HashSet<int>();

            int _lock3 = 0;
            var hashset3 = new HashSet<int>();

            Parallel.ForEach(list, item =>

            {
                /******************/
                lock (_lock1)
                    hashset1.Add(item);
                /******************/

                /******************/
                SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _lock2, 1, 0) == 1);

                hashset2.Add(item);

                _lock2 = 0;
                /******************/

                /******************/
                SpinWait spin = new SpinWait();
                while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _lock3, 1, 0) == 1)
                    spin.SpinOnce();

                hashset3.Add(item);

                _lock3 = 0;
                /******************/

            });


            Console.WriteLine("Lock: {0}", hashset1.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("SpinWaitUntil: {0}", hashset2.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("SpinWait: {0}", hashset3.Count);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a concurrent hash set-like data type, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18923091/7565574? These are optimized for concurrent access often in such a way that they don't even need locks.

Comment: What's wrong with a `lock`? Have you looked at the `SemaphoreSlim` class? This is a good alternative and much easier to reason about.

Comment: @ckuri in my code, this is a add only scenario and concurrent dictionary is optimized for read, i have no gain to use it

Comment: @tigerswithguitars looking at the code of that https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs it use a mix of spinwait & lock & moniter, a bit heavy

Comment: For a bit of clarity, would be helpful to have a bit more detail about why a `lock` is not applicable and `SemaphoreSlim` is too heavy. Seems the use case is important and this is an interesting question.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars i'm trying to gain as much as optimization as possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The condition used in SpinWait.SpinUntil is wrong.

1. [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the original value of the variable.
2. MSDN docs of [SpinWait.SpinUntil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449193(v=vs.110).aspx) says, condition is

> A delegate to be executed over and over until it returns true.

You want to spin until a 0 -> 1 transition occurs, so the condition should be

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref fun, 1, 0) == 0
```

Subsequent calls to CompareExchange on other threads results in 1, so they will wait until the `fun` flag is restored to 0 by the "winner" thread.

Some further remarks:

- `fun = 0;` should work on x86 architecture, but I'm not sure it's correct everywhere. If you use Interlocked to access a field, it's a best practice to use Interlocked for all access to that field. So I suggest `Interlocked.Exchange(ref fun, 0)` instead.
- SpinWait is rarely a good solution regarding performance as it prevents the OS putting the spinning thread into an idle state. It should be used for very short waits only. ([An example of a proper usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim(v=vs.110).aspx)). Simple locks (aka Monitor.Enter/Exit) or SemaphoreSlim will do in general or you can consider ReaderWriterLockSlim if # of reads >> # of writes.

Comment: the way I'm using the CompareExchange is the proper way to simulate a lock, other online example simply do a != original value, I do a == new value instead, if i was going to go with == 0, it would / is blow up in a fraction of a seconds since it would be like there was no lock in place, doing the Exchange directly would also not do what I am expecting which is stop if there is another thread working on that part of the code. for the use of spinwait, it is clearly identified that it should be used for **VERY SHORT** period of time, the operation, add to hashset, should fall into that category

Comment: CompareExchange returns the **original value**, the value before change, if any. CompareExchange returning 0 means that the flag was 0 and has been changed to 1 during the current call. In any other cases, CompareExchange returns 1, which means "the lock is taken".

Comment: @Fredou Try [this code](https://gist.github.com/adams85/06dc084c4b368624a935aac92fb7c77f). I hope this will convince you.

Comment: this code example doesn't do real multi thread, just put a loop inside the task surrounding the whole code, one task will run X amount of time then the second one will start for X amount of time, it wont switch between thread.

Comment: but your right, for the SpinUntil, the compareExchange is supose to be the reverse of the instance of a SpintWait logic which caused my confusion

Comment: @Fredou The code example is just for demonstrating that the lock construction works as expected.