# HashSet UnionWith AddIfNotPresent deadlock

Tags: c#

When invoking `UnionWith` on a `HashSet<T>` in two threads I have experienced an infinite loop/deadlock when both threads are invoking `AddIfNotPresent`. 
I know that `HashSet<T>` is not designed to be thread-safe but looking at the implementation I couldn't find out why it would cause a deadlock ([referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,71347988796dc52f,references)).

Why would invoking `UnionWith` on a `HashSet<T>` in two threads cause a deadlock?

In other words: Why is `HashSet<T>` not thread safe?

Example for reference:

```
HashSet<Foo> points = new HashSet<Foo>();

Parallel.For(0, 2, e =>
{
    points.UnionWith(new List<Foo>() { new Foo() });
});
```

Comment: `HashSet<T>` is not *thread safe*. Try `ConcurrentDictionary`; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922985/concurrent-hashsett-in-net-framework

Comment: Are you asking why HashSet is not thread safe?

Comment: Your example don't reproduce the deadlock. I can only have a NullReferenceException. What version of .NET is using?

Comment: Correct, I'm asking why HashSet is not thread safe.

Comment: The answer is that it was not written to be thread safe.

Comment: By the way, did you happen to get an exception? I noticed that sometimes I'm getting a NullReferenceException when running your example. And it seems to be connected with HashSet initialization inside AddIfNotPresent as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through the call chain, the method *may* call `AddIfNotPresent` which in turn *may* call `IncreaseCapacity` which calls `SetCapacity` which in turn copies the whole internal array into a new one. That is *obviously* not thread safe without any synchronization measures.

Lots of other things are probably not thread safe as well, but that one should be the most obvious.