# Ping pong between 2 points fails

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move a object between 2 points in unity3d, seems there are lot of answers to this topic but i always get a error that I don't know how to solve when I try to solve this, so actually I tried to do this:

```
void Update () {
    transform.position = Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time,10.0f), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

I get this error:

> Assets/PingPong.cs(7,38): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type`, where a `variable`, `value` or `method group` was expected

What am I doing wrong? I'm a beginner need some help with this stuff :/

Comment: Did you forget the `new` keyword before `Vector3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a `Vector3` with x, y and z value, you have to use the `new` keyword.

```
transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 10.0f), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

One exception is when using the static `Vector3` functions that returns predefined `Vector3` values such as `Vector3.zero`,`Vector3.back` and the rest.

`Vector3` is a `struct` datatype.You can learn why you need to use the `new` keyword when creating new Vector3(struct)[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9207488/3785314).

Comment: Will fix the error, but doesn't explain or answer the question.

Comment: @devRicher I just put a link to that since that part of question has been answered before.

Comment: i got the answer, and it works kinda well, but how can i increase speed and control the begin and end point?

Comment: You can make a float variable that controls the speed then multiply it by `Mathf.PingPong` value. For example, `float speed = 100` then you can do `transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 10.0f) * speed, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`

Comment: hmm thank you very much that was great, and how can i control the begin and end point?

Comment: You can create a new question about that and also explain what you mean by end point. I think that the comment section is getting into other issues not related to the problem in the question