# Why vector3 NewPosition = (1,1,1) is not valid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why the command line

```
vector3 NewPosition = (1,1,1);
```

is invalid? While the command line is valid

```
Vector3 NewPosition = new Vector3(1,1,1);
```

why using the command line below, is accepted without using the word "new"? Isn't transform.position also containt 3 value of (x,y,z)?

```
Vector3 NewPosition = transform.position
```

By writing "Vector3 NewPosition" isn't that it already recognize "NewPosition" as a memory storage area for "Vector3" type data? just like int a=1? I'm quite lost in spotting the difference.

Comment: With C# 9, you could have `Vector3 NewPosition = new (1,1,1);`, but that's probably as close as you'll get for now https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#target-typed-new-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# only certain types can be instantiated without using the `new` keyword by simply assigning a value to them.

1. Most prominent are [primitive types](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types) (e.g. int, float);
2. [`Structs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) which provide public fields. (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767669/why-is-it-possible-to-instantiate-a-struct-without-the-new-keyword), it also provides an explanation). In this case however you can only use the fields you assigned.

In those cases you are allowed to simply A) declare your variable, B) assign a value/some values for structs and C) use it afterwards.

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;
}

public class Usage
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        MyStruct myStruct;
        myStruct.X = 1;
        myStruct.Y = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(myStruct.X);
        Console.WriteLine(myStruct.Y);
        //Console.WriteLine(myStruct.Z); causes an error, since Z is still unassigned
    }
}
```

[C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9) makes the `new` keyword target-typed allowing to omit stating the obvious data type for creation.

```
List<string> myList = new();
// instead of
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```