# Does System.Array perform boxing on value types or not?

Tags: c#, arrays, boxing

I recently did some rough performance measuring on `List<>` vs `[]` for an array of small structures. System.Array seemed to win hands down so I went with that.

It's only just dawned on me that System.Array contains object types, so surely filling it with structures would cause boxing to occur?

However, [the MSDN entry for System.Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) states:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the Array class implements the
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`,
>   `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The
>   implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are
>   not visible to the documentation build tools. As a result, the generic
>   interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array
>   class, and there are no reference topics for interface members that
>   are accessible only by casting an array to the generic interface type
>   (explicit interface implementations).

Does this mean that boxing does not occur after all? (And would explain my performance results)

Comment: In order to explain your performance results probably we should see the code you used to measure performance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No using an array does not box if you use the indexer notation. 
e.g.

```
new int[2];
x=[1]=3;
```

Compiles to the following IL (note the line numbers are irrelevant as they come from some other snippet of code)

```
IL_0011: ldc.i4.2
IL_0012: newarr System.Int32
IL_0017: stfld Int32[] x
IL_001c: ldarg.0
IL_001d: ldfld Int32[] x
IL_0022: ldc.i4.1
IL_0023: ldc.i4.3
IL_0024: stelem.i4
```

For languages that cannot use the indexer (and I don't really know if they exist or not) 2 other methods are created at compile time for Arrays.

It creates these public methods::

```
public int Get(int index)
public void Set(int index,int value)
```

Those methods don't box either and are not normally accessible through C#. (Don't ask me why they are public methods). You can execute them using IL or by creating delegates to them. They are slower as you are forced to do a callvirt to invoke these methods.

The stelem.* and ldelem.* family is used to handle storing to a strongly typed array type. When using generics usually the following prefixes are attached `constrained` or `readonly` when using a `T[]`. `stelem.*` type usually do not check type. E.g. using `stelem.i4` is faster than using `stelem.any Int32` unless you prefix it with `readonly` because otherwise it forces a type check.

Now the typecheck is COMPLETELY useless on valuetype arrays are they are not covariant!

Because the runtime generates the one dimensional array starting at zero (either called SZ_array or vector type) type they are natively known.

There are a family of il op codes for them: `newarr`,`stelem.*`,`ldelem.*`,`ldlen` etc.

The `List<T>` type uses a `T[]` for its backing store in the microsoft implementation of the BCL. `List<T>` does not box. Regardless of using list or array you are storing things in an array.

Comment: Here's a supplementary link to another answer regarding heap/stack allocation of arrays and their contained values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113819/arrays-heap-and-stack-and-value-types/1114152#1114152

Comment: Since Arrays are reference types, the unboxed int's are stored in the managed heap as well - there's nothing to box about.