# Is "string s;" compiled to "string s = new String(..);"?

Tags: c#, string

String is not value type, but we still use it like it's value type. So, is `string s;` compiled to something like `string s = new String(..);`?

Comment: When you do `string s;`, nothing is instantiated.

Comment: But, if it's not a value type it has to be instantiated with `new`, isn't it?

Comment: @theateist what would you expect this to do:  `string s = null`?

Comment: string s; or object o; are the same thing. Each are stack space initialized with null (supposing they are local variable). Then when you decide to use it, you will be forced to inizialize with a real value like s = string.Empty; or s = "Hello world";

Comment: A string variable is instantiated when you assign some text to it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define `string s;` you only define a reference, which currently points to nothing at all. As string is a reference type, the compiler will not generate `string s = new String(..);`. You may understand it as `string s = null;` will be the compilation result.

For value types, such as int, the case is different. For example, when you define `int i;`, it will compile to `int i = 0;` where 0 is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my confusion: after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113819/arrays-heap-and-stack-and-value-types) post I understood that stack will hold reference to `s` that will allocated in heap after initialization.

Comment: I don't know who down voted, but your understanding here is much better than the one you expressed in the question. However, it still only covers some of the string mystery. There is another important thing that makes string special, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned.aspx